# Writing a function that operates on a vector in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, for-loop, vector

I am trying to operate the following function on a vector (of t) but I get the following error:

```
    rho.prime <- function(t, k=19000){
  for (i in seq(1,length(t))){
    if (abs(t[i]) <= k)
    { print(2*t[i])
      return(2*t[i])
    }
    else 
    {
      print(2*k*sign(t[i]))
      return(2*k*sign(t[i]))
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the rho.prime function description:
[image]

The problem is that I am suspicious about the result:

```
> t=c(1,3,5,7,10)
> t
[1]  1  3  5  7 10
> rho.prime(t,k)
[1] 2
[1] 2
```

Comment: Check the `ifelse`function, it operates on vectors.

Comment: The problem with your code is that the function call exits when it encounters the first `return` within the first loop iteration. If you were to keep a `for` loop, you would have to 1) initialize `out <- rep(NA, length(t))` before the loop 2) do `out[i] <- ...` instead of `return(...)` inside the loop 3) `return(out)` after the loop. nograpes' solution is much better though.

Comment: Why did someone downvote this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function could look like this:

```
rho<-function(t,k) ifelse(abs(t)<=k,t^2,(2*k*abs(t))-k^2)
```

Comment: I checked your update, and found that it was merely a small modification to your function, calling another function `sign`. Study the function that I have written for `rho`; it should be easy to modify it to your needs.

Comment: very nice implementation. I liked it much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Flodel and Fernando I could come up with this solution:

```
rho.prime <- function(t, k=19000){
  out <- rep(NA, length(t))
  for (i in seq(1,length(t))){
    if (abs(t[i]) <= k)
    { print(2*t[i])
      out[i] <- 2*t[i] 
    }
    else 
    {
      print(2*k*sign(t[i]))
      out[i] <- 2*k*sign(t[i])
    }
  }
  return(out)
}
```

Please let me know if this is correct or not.

```
> t
[1]  1  3  5  7 10
> rho.prime(t,k)
[1] 2
[1] 6
[1] 10
[1] 14
[1] 20
[1]  2  6 10 14 20
```